# How to pass common object between Worker Service and WebService with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, service, asp.net-core-webapi

I have written a .net core 3 workerservice which also has a webapi built into the same project - the purpose is to enable the hosted workerservice to present a healthcheck webapi which can be interrogated to provide the worker service status information.  We use a common pattern to add healthcheck calls to all our webapi microservices.

The workerservice and webapi both work fine in themselves but I cannot work out how to inject a common object into the two services to be used to pass the data back and forth between the two.

I presume that I have to create the status object in the CreateHostBuilder method of the Program class and inject it into both but cannot find any suitable methods to pass it.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            // HealthCheck WebAPI
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                                        {
                                            webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                                            webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                                            webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                                            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                                        })
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
                                        {
                                            configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                                            configHost.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: false);
                                        })
            // WorkerService
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
                                        {
                                            config
                                                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                                                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json", optional: false);

                                            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                                        })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                                {
                                    services.AddOptions();
                                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                                });
```

The status object could be something like...

```
    public class StatusInfo
    {
        public DateTime LastRun { get; set; }
        public int LastAdded { get; set; }
        public int LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }
```

Anyone help me out here, please?

Comment: Show examples of how the status is created and consumed.

Comment: One common object, created and injected into both services so that the worker service can update the values and the webapi can read them, nothing more complex than that.

Comment: Just create a service that knows how to persist and retrieve the shared data. Inject that service into the worker to persist data and inject it into the controller to retrieve the data.

Comment: Make sense, I was thinking too simple, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a service that knows how to persist and retrieve the shared data.

Over simplified abstraction

```
public interface IStatusService {
    Task Save(StatusInfo status);
    Task<StatusInfo> Get();
}
```

Inject that service into the worker to persist data and inject it into the controller to retrieve the data.

Comment: Turned out that I could DI a relatively simple object containing some static primitives (dates, strings, etc.) and that happily transferred the required data back and forth.  Thanks again for your help.